# How to blur/disable parent component when child page (popup page) is opened?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React. I want to know about the easiest way on how to to blur parent component when child page (popup page) is opened.

Here is my Fiddle Workspace [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7pqw4568q)

Even if I blur it the parent should still be clickable
Can anyone show how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: If you blur it, do you still want it to be be clickable?

Comment: @yourfavoritedev Yes even if I blur it it should be clickable

Comment: @yourfavoritedev Yes even if I blur it it should be clickable and can you kindly show me how to make the child close when the blurred area of parent is clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use CSS to blur the parent component. Something like this:

1. We will wrap the child component into a div with the class name as `overlay`
2. Apply CSS effect to blur the parent component

[Note: You can also add the click event to the blur areas by adding the event to the `overlay` div]

```js
{this.state.childOpen && (
  <div className="overlay">
    <div className="overlay-opacity" />
    <Child data={data} applyFilter={this.applyFilter} />
  </div>
)}
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.overlay-opacity {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrnr2ryk3m)

To hide the child component onclick of the blur area, we can add a event like this

```js
hideChild() {
  this.setState({
    childOpen: false
  });
}
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/046w69y330)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Now it worked. But even if I blur it it should be clickable. As of now it parent is blurred when child was opened but parent is no longer clickable.

Comment: can you show me one thing - how to make the child close when the blurred area of parent is clicked.

Comment: marked you as correct. Just one thing - can you explain the requirement of these two classes - overlay and .overlay-opacity. Why have you used 2 classes?

Comment: @tommy123 The `overlay` is just to wrap the chid component and the `overlay-opacity` div. The `overlay-opacity` div is used for the blur effects and to handle the click event to hide the child component when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on react, I would like to suggest you to use `react-responsive-modal` library. You can install this using npm.
It is easily customizable via props. 
Please find the example below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/9jxp669j2o

Answer (score -1):

What i understood is that you want to blur the table when child is opened
Here is code you need to add

```
formatStyle = () => {
  if (this.state.childOpen == true) return { filter: "blur(5px)" };
   else return {};
};
//add formatStyle in main app
styleData={this.formatStyle()}  // in props on table
style = {this.props.styleData} //add this attribute in main container of table component
styleData={this.formatStyle()} // Pass this in ReactTable in main app
```

Comment: Can you show in a codeSandbox, also there is one more requirement - how to make the child close when the blurred area of parent is clicked

Comment: add complete project with react table inside that

Comment: for that requirement
`onClick={this.closeChild}
onClick = () => {this.setState({childOpen:false})}
`

Answer (score -1):

The feature you are looking for is already in Semantic-UI-React Modal. This is very easy to use, you only have to pass some props to get above result.

demo https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#variations-dimmer